# What prevents microverse inhabitants from leaving their own universes, and entering the ones containing them?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In the episode [The Ricks Must Be Crazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ricks_Must_Be_Crazy) from the TV series Rick and Morty, Rick and Morty got shrunken down when they entered the microverse that Rick created.  There, the 2 of them, along with Zeep who created *his* miniverse, got shrunken into that.

I'm assuming that if Zeep could've transported himself to fight Rick in Rick's own universe, he would've done so.  However, there must've be some scientific reason preventing him from doing so.  Can someone elaborate on why this is?  You can shrink down atoms, but making them larger just simply doesn't work that way?

Comment: aah, but the dead santa. It does work that way as well

Comment: Why doesn't Rick turn larger and get out of the universe? He doesn't think it is possible. The moment Zeep realized what happened and that it is possible, he tried it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this question correctly, but no, from what I remember, Zeep **could** go into the biggest universe.

The reason Zeep didn't go into Rick's universe is because Rick got to the transporter/enlarger first and beat Zeep in a fist fight. Zeep then realized that when Rick got to the biggest universe he would toss away the battery and destroy the micro verse that Zeep inhabited  if it didn't generate power for Rick.

If you're asking why Zeep didn't enlarge himself once Rick got into the car/ship, then I'm guessing Rick did something to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Given how much more time passes in the microverse vs. in the (regular) universe, I'm guessing Zeep still had a shot to get out and fight Rick in the regular universe.  However, I don't recall Rick did anything that would've blocked Zeep, but I can accept that "happened in the background".  Would like to know if this was ever covered though